# Xcode 12, Workspaces and the new "XCFrameworks" not working together

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, dependencies

I have a project, made up multiple smaller projects.  I manage this mess generally through Carthage, but for development, I make use of a `xcworkspace`, to make it easier and faster to make changes, and Xcode to build the child and master projects via the workspace.

I've recently started updating all the projects to make use of the new `XCFrameworks` format (instead of the "fat frameworks" which Carthage/Xcode use to generate).

If I'm just working on the root project (`xcproject`) and linking the `XCFrameworks` directly, it all works fine.  The moment I switch to the `xcworkspace` and replace any of the `XCFrameworks` with it's XCProject, the build fails

```
Multiple commands produce '/Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gnuwolzggqlzhlfiipjzbigitmvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/....framework':
1) Command: ProcessXCFramework /Users/.../Development/.../.../Carthage/Build/....xcframework /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gnuwolzggqlzhlfiipjzbigitmvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/....framework ios
2) Command: ProcessXCFramework /Users/shanew/Development/.../Libraries/.../Carthage/Build/....xcframework /Users/.../Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/gnuwolzggqlzhlfiipjzbigitmvu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/....framework ios
```

The sub project frameworks DO NOT embedded their dependencies (as if I recall, this caused other issues) and dependency management is managed through Carthage, so the root project AND the child project will share dependencies, which I think is the cause of the issue.

I had some "minor" luck, if I built the sub project first and then remove its "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content", I could get the root project to work, but when I tried to do this with multiple sub projects I started to run into issues.

I did note that when I remove the `xcframeworks` and replace it with the project, it displays the project with the "fat framework" icon, instead of the `xcframeworks` icon ... I doubt this part of the issue, but thought I'd mention it...

[image: Selector]

So, the question...

How do we include "sub projects"/"frameworks", which have `xcframeworks` dependencies (shared with other projects) into a `xcworkspace` and have it build without triggering the "Multiple commands produce ... output" errors.

Comment: I have this very same problem under similar circumstances. So far, one workaround is to remove the Build symlinks under Carthage/Checkouts, but this feels like a huge hack. I am trying to come up with a better way to resolve these errors.

Comment: Hi. Did you find a way to solve this? Thanks

Comment: @superjos No - I've been lucky enough to be able to move onto Swift Packages - but that original project made use of a lot sub binary dependencies, which (at the time) Swift Packages didn't support

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this totally maps to OP scenario, but here's what worked for us.

Initial, working setup with .framework:

- Workspace

  - Framework project

    - Depends on 3rd-party framework ZZZ, through Carthage
    - Has its own Carthage cartfile and Carthage directory
    - Linked to ZZZ .framework binary from Carthage\Build
  - Application project

    - Depends on Framework, through Xcode target dependency
    - Depends on 3rd-party framework ZZZ, through Carthage
    - Has its own Carthage cartfile and Carthage directory
    - Embeds and linked to ZZZ .framework binary from Carthage\Build

Then we moved 3rd-party dependency ZZZ to XCFramework, still through Carthage, and the same setup was *not* working anymore. Our framework was building fine, but building our application failed because multiple commands where trying to produce ZZZ.

What worked for us, in the end, was to modify Application project and the way it includes the 3rd-party framework ZZZ. Instead of having its own Carthage-managed dependency, build directory, built binary, etc. for the 3rd-party dependency, the Application project embedded and linked the *same* binary taken from our Framework Carthage\Build directory.

So a setup like the following:

- Workspace

  - Framework project

    - Depends on 3rd-party framework ZZZ, through Carthage
    - Has its own Carthage cartfile and Carthage directory
    - Linked to ZZZ XCFramework binary from Carthage\Build
  - Application project

    - Depends on Framework, through Xcode target dependency
    - Does **not explictly** depend on 3rd-party framework ZZZ, through Carthage
    - Has **no** own Carthage cartfile and Carthage directory

      - (or anyway the 3rd-party framework is not listed there)
    - Embeds and linked to ZZZ XCFramework binary from **Framework\Carthage\Build**

Hope that makes sense.

The story is different when an Application project depends on our Framework not through Xcode target dependency, but through the raw XCFramework file copied somewhere. In that case, Application project must again explicitly depend on 3rd-party framework ZZZ through Carthage, and embed/link the XCFramework binary from its own Carthage\Build directory.